# What should be the file upload path for CommonsMultipartFile if I want to save the files in the project path?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, file-upload, file-io

I want to upload a file into my project relative path.

webapp/fileUpload/ is the path that I want the file to upload.

so when I give the path as

```
 CommonsMultipartFile commonsFile = user.getImage();
 String fileName = commonsFile.getOriginalFilename();

 File destFile = new File("http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/fileUpload/",fileName);
```

Its giving me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\SpringDemo\fileUpload\design.txt(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

I am not understanding what should be the right path.

```
I want to save it under my project folder and not on any other path so I am using  http:\localhost:8080\SpringDemo\fileUpload\as the path.

When i paste http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/fileUpload/abc.txt into my browser it shows me the file.(abc.txt)
```

I am not understanding what should be the right path.

Kindly suggest me the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Zingo

Answer (score 0):

First off, any files you save within the context will be lost if you undeploy the app, so make sure that's what you want.

As to your question, `http://localhost/etc/and/so/on` is the URL for your app, not the file path.

The file path is the real path of the underlying filesystem.

Let's say you're using Tomcat, which is installed in /usr/share, a file path within your app might be like: `/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/yourapp/somewhere/you/want/files/stored/some-file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The location you specified is a directory, not a file. Also, I would recommend send the file in parts to a php/jsp which will do the work of making additional checks and finally store it.